# Change HTML in table TD

Tags: jquery

In the table supplied below, how to I target `fred` so I can change `one` to `1`?

```
  <table>
  <tr id="fred">
  <td>one</td>
  <td>two</td>
  <td>three</td>
  <tr>
  <tr id="wilma">
  <td>one</td>
  <td>two</td>
  <td>three</td>
  <tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: `$("#fred td:first-child")` http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Simple use "nth"

```
 $("#fred").find("td:nth(0)").html('1');
 $("#fred").find("td:nth(1)").html('2');
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This is really basic DOM manipulation so it would make sense for you to try this yourself first.

In any case, assuming you have access to jQuery:

```
(function () {
    $('tr#fred>:first-child').text('1');    
})();
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5VMLM/